# MariaDB Dynamic Columns & JSON?

Tags: json, database, mariadb

I am trying to store JSON data (pretty much an array in PHP that could be unknown length) in a column which would allow me to do where queries on it. Let's use this as an example...

Say I have a field asking what sort of sports you like (and it's a checkbox).

```
[] Soccer
[] Hockey
[] Football
[] Swimming
```

Which would then be sent via `sports[]` array to PHP. I then want to take this and add it to my database so it looks like

```
|sports|{hockey:false,swimming:true,football:false,soccer:true}|
```

Or something like that, which I could then maybe go

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM fields WHERE hockey = "false";
```

And I can't seem to figure out how to properly do this, ignore the fact that this "example" could actually easily be done by joining I want to do it using mariadb dynamic columns (at least I believe that's what I want). I know I can do this using Postgre.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's all here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/dynamic-columns/

The dynamic columns are stored inside a real `blob` column and inserted like that:

```
insert into data
values (data_id, user_id, COLUMN_CREATE(<dcolumn1>, <value1>, <dcolumn2>, <value2>, ...));
```

So you would not use json here, instead serialize the data this way:

```
$dynamic = array()
foreach($_POST['sports'] as $sport) {
    $dynamicData[] = "'" . $sport . "'", TRUE;
}
$dynamicColumn = join(', ', $dynamicData);
```

Will generate something like

```
'hockey', TRUE, 'soccer', TRUE
```

To search all rows for ppl playing soccer:

```
... where COLUMN_GET(dynamic_blob, 'soccer' as soccer) = TRUE;
```